# Div position behind the header div

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone my tutorial has a tree div for now. Header,container and footer. header is fixed. but if you check it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mustafaozturk74/8eSAU/) you see container div has a **problem lags behind the header div** i can not solv the problem. what can i do in my css code?

This is **HTML code**:

```
<div class="globalHeader">
    <div class="globalheader-in"></div>
</div>
    <div class="global_container">
    <div class="container">
        1 <br>2 <br>3 <br>4 <br>5 <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

And **CSS code**:

```
.global_container {
    clear:both;
    width:981px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-right:1px solid #d8dbdf;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
}

.container {
    float:left;
    width:981px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}

.globalHeader {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#2a3542;
    z-index:99999;
}

.globalheader-in {
    width:981px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: please explain your problem PROPERLY .

Comment: That's not his fault. Multiple people understood his question. Chillax. Takma kardes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/8eSAU/5/**

```
.global_container{
    clear:both;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}
```

It was not working, because you simply hid the text beneath the fixed element.

Kolay gelsin :)

Comment: eywallah . Diğer eklediğim divler de sıkıntı çıkıyodu top:40px yaptım ama bu kez de header div i aşağı kaydı position relative olarak düşünmemiştim :)

Comment: Sorun degil kardesim, insanlik hali. For people who want to read it in English (which I can understand). He said that he didn't think of using `position: relative` and that's why it did not work. Now it's solved, I thanked him, he thanked me, that's it. No need to flag.

Comment: This isn't really a good solution. If you look at the size of the HTML-element and the BODY-element you'll see that their height 40px to small. It might be fine for now but can cause problem if you add more advanced functions.

Answer (score 1):

### Using a spacer

You can push the content of `container` down by adding a spacer element as the first child of the container.

```css
.container:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 40px;  /* equal to the height of the header */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/8eSAU/2/)**.

### Using top padding

You can also use `padding-top` for the container to achieve that:

```css
.container {
    width:981px;
    height:100px;
    /* other styles... */
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/8eSAU/9/)**.

However If you want to keep the height of the container as `100px`, you should use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to calculate the height of the container including paddings and borders, as follows:

```
.container {
    width:981px;
    height:100px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/8eSAU/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Why not add:

```
position:relative;
top:40px;
```

To `.global_container {`

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/8eSAU/1/)

This assumes you wish the header to scroll with the content, in which case all you need to do per the demo is offset the top of the content by the height of the header, so it initially displays below it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `padding-top` will take care of that.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/8eSAU/4/)

```
.global_container{
    clear:both;
    width:981px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-right:1px solid #d8dbdf;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
        padding-top:40px; /* heigt of fixed header */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add padding-top to the .global_container or body

padding-top should be same as height of header.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the link below for the Fiddle

Add the following to global_container class

```
position:absolute;
top:47px;
```

**[FIND FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/h3ju9/)**